# пишу телеграм бота на питоне

Tags: telegram-bot

что означает строка @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мда. Вы вообще пытались сами узнать что это?
Это декоратор для функции, благодаря нему, при запуске,  бот вообще знает о ее существовании.

`message_handler` говорит, что он реагирует только на сообщения, еще есть `callback_query_handler` который отлавливает колбеки от инлайн кнопок. `content_types=["text"]` это фильтр для хендлера, который принимает только текст.